# Processing files on server before moving it to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

The idea behind the application is to record videos from webcams with `WebRTC`, the problem is Chrome sending back two blobs: audio `wav` and video `webm` so I do processing on both of them to make a final `.mp4` with `fmpeg` library from rails.

I upload both blobs with `dragonfly` gem, and do the processing with the tilde command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i #{avi_name}.avi -i #{audio_name}.mp3  -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -ac 2 #{avi_name}.mp4
```

That works fine on local development, on production it's impossible to do it on S3 buckets - our videos and images goes to s3 bucket - I've tried it with no hopes. Also I've searched to see if anyone made any success, but no.

So I may upload it to our server acting as a temp server, then move it to S3. I use `dragonfly` for uploading and serving images, so it handles the upload nicely, but how can I achieve the goal with it?

Comment: Does Dragonfly support pre-processing? If so, that's your answer. Also be **extremely** careful when inserting user data in command-line statements like that. Not only does this not support filenames with spaces, a fairly common occurrence, but it will allow people to **completely trash your system**. Use [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) on all arguments to avoid this, or pass them in individually to a `system` call.

Comment: no it doesn't support pre-processing, it does that only for images on the fly and that's a killer for memory of course, if some how I managed to do same with videos. thanks for the caution.